# Service timed out Spreadsheets -- Possible to pause Sheets refresh while script runs?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an MCC Google Ads script that runs a report on each Google Ads account and puts it into a Google spreadsheet tab. While the Google Ads script runs quickly, the spreadsheet service times out 80%+ of the time. It appears  the issue is driven by the pivot tables/formulas in my spreadsheet that are calculating, making the spreadsheet unavailable for the Ads Script to run the report.exportToSheet function. I can confirm this because if I delete all pivot tables, etc the script works perfectly.

I'm asking if it is possible to stop the Google sheet from calculating all pivot tables/formulas while the script runs so it can export the data?

```
function main(){

 // Get the accounts to be processed.
 var accountSelector = AdsManagerApp.accounts()
   .withIds([MY IDs]);

    accountSelector.executeInParallel("processClientAccount");
}

function processClientAccount() {
  var clientAccount = AdsApp.currentAccount();

  // Process your client account here.
  // Generate reports
    generateReports(clientAccount.getName())
}


function generateReports(accountName){


   //Pulls the Report Data
  var report = AdWordsApp.report("SELECT AccountDescriptiveName, CampaignName, Date, HourOfDay, Clicks, Cost FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE CampaignName DOES_NOT_CONTAIN_IGNORE_CASE 'BCM' AND Clicks > 0 DURING TODAY");

  //Defines the spreadsheet to put the report data in
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('URL');

  //Sets up variable for function to get a specific tab (matching account name) or creating it. 
  var sheet = createOrGetSheet(spreadsheet, accountName, 12);

  //Exports the Report Data To the Google Sheet
  report.exportToSheet(sheet);

}

  //Code for the function to select spreadsheet tab or create a new one

function createOrGetSheet(reportSpreadsheet, name, position) {

 var sheet = reportSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(name);
 if(sheet == null) {
  return reportSpreadsheet.insertSheet(name, position);
 } else {
  return sheet;
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you executing the script when opening the Spreadsheet? Or do you trigger it from outside?

Comment: @Jescanellas I am running the script from Google Ads Scripts

Comment: Unfortunately it is not supported to pause sheets formulas. Maybe if you could run the script from the cloud before opening it..